# Rapid vs Gradual changes in pressure

Tags: pressure

I was watching a mythbusters in class where the diver is sucked into the helmet because of a rapid change in pressure. This happened at 300 ft beneath the surface. If that strong of a reaction happens at that depth, how can diver's safely go to even lower depths? Is it because the change in pressure is gradual vs instantaneous?

Answer (score 1):

Under normal operating conditions, a diver using a helmet that receives surface supplied gas is at equilibrium with the ambient water pressure regardless of what depth the diver is at.

In the event of the surface compressor failing or supply line rupturing , the helmet has a check valve so that the gas, under compression in the helmet doesn't flow up the supply line.

The issue of being squeezed into the helmet happens when there is a supply failure AND a failure of the check valve. And when this occurs, the deeper the diver is, the greater the forces squeezing the diver into the helmet.

Regardless of the experiments the Myth busters may have done, and what their conclusions were, this form of squeeze is a real hazard that has been documented in both commercial and naval diving practice.

Comment: By the way for divers tended by surface supplied gas 300 ft is about the practical limit, not because of the hazard you mention, but rather lengthy decompression cycles. Much beyond that depth, divers are kept under pressure at the surface and moved to the work site when needed. In this case the gas differences on the supply lines from the diving bell are much lower.